# Can't run python script in browser using Spyder IDE

Tags: python, spyder

Can someone tell me how to run python script from Spyder IDE in browser?
I have my web app written in PyCharm, and in PyCharm I configure my run button to execute this file manage.py

```
from app import create_app

app = create_app('default')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=5000, debug=True)
```

And when I click run button, I started server
C:/path/to/my/project/manage.py
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 126-829-386
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

And I only type this localhost IP and port in my browser, and my app is working on 127.0.0.1:5000

How to do this in Spyder, I don't see any configuration option for starting my app in browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) There's no configuration to define a master file per project, so every time you press the run button, Spyder runs the same file.

This is something we plan to add for Spyder 4, to be released on 2019.

Comment: Thanks Carlos. So can you tell me how to develop and test my app in browser using Spyder IDE? Actually how to run my Flask app in browser? I can do that using my Git Bash terminal but it would be much easier to run directly from Spyder.

Comment: I try to execute that file but I get this error. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_sqlalchemy'. I've already installed that module using pip install in bash terminal ---- Requirement already satisfied: flask_sqlalchemy in d:\path\to\project\flaskvenv\lib\site-packages. Does Spider maybe try to find in some another directory this module?

Comment: This is a typical installation problem, so it's outside of the scope of Spyder. You just need to be sure that the interpreter in Spyder's consoles and the one in your terminal is the same (which clearly seems not the case).